# Digitizing photographs of a map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, maps, envi, digitizing

Is it possible to digitize the photographs of very old maps, having no co-ordinates. The photographs are exactly like [this](https://www.twenty20.com/photos/18c4ed19-469c-4786-9179-619b759300b0). If possible, could somebody tell me how to proceed? I have access to ArcGIS and ENVI.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you have ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcGIS(ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro) you can achieve this using georeferencing.

**Georeferencing:** It is the process of taking a digital image, it could be an air photo, a scanned geologic map, or a picture of a topographic map, and adding geographic information to the image so that GIS or mapping software can 'place' the image in its appropriate real-world location.

In simpler terms, we use reference data that has a coordinate system assigned, and the target is known locations/points on the historical data to assign the information to it. The selected points are known as control points.

I tried looking at the shared link, and the home page shows a historical image of Old Midnapur(W.B) in India. In this case, the Contol points can be taken as the delta formation.

**The Historical Map**:

[image]

Now we have to decide some control points by looking at the referenced data, so here you can use the default TopoGraphic map provided by ESRI.

**Comparing data for deciding control points:**

[image]

Once the conrol points are found, you are set to work and perform the georeferening task:

1. To display the Georeferencing toolbar, click the Customize menu and click Toolbars > Georeferencing.
2. In the table of contents, right-click a target layer (the referenced dataset) and click Zoom to Layer.
3. From the Georeferencing toolbar, click the Layer drop-down arrow and choose the raster layer you want to georeference.
4. Click the Georeferencing drop-down menu and click Fit To Display.
   This displays the raster dataset in the same area as the target layers. Click the Add Control Points tool Add Control Points to add control points.
5. I have just taken two points for demonstration and the map was almost brought to its correct location, you can take multiple points and perfom the task in a clock wise direction.
6. After adding control points, click the Georeferencing drop-down menu and click either Update Georeferencing or Rectify. Updating the georeferencing will save the transformation information with the raster and its auxiliary files. Rectifying will create a new file with the georeferencing information.

**The Result:**

[image]

I am sharing a few helpful documents for reference:

- [Georeferencing Historical Maps](https://storymaps.arcgis.com/stories/dd75d0398f7d4ded924d303161895b8b)
- [Georeference historical imagery in ArcGIS Pro](https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/georeference-imagery-in-arcgis-pro/)
- [ArcGIS Lesson 3: Georeferencing Maps](https://geospatialhistorian.wordpress.com/lessons/arcgis-lesson-3-georeferencing-maps/)
- [Georeferencing - making historic maps spatial](https://spatial.scholarslab.org/making-historic-maps-spatial-georeferencing/)

**P.S**: The Web Site you shared did now allowed a free data download, I have taken a screenshot and used it in ArcMap :)

Comment: This has helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is called "georeferencing" and requires knowing the real coordinates (latitude/longitude) of some features on the image.

A Georeferencer program will input your image, then you have a workflow like clicking on a point on the image, and then clicking on a world map of where that point is. So for example your image might have some dots for cities, and you click each dot in turn and then click that city centre on a world map. You can also use prominent features as points such as intersections of boundary lines, headlands, or river junctions, as long as you can see them on the image and can find them on the world map.

Once enough corresponding points have been entered the program will produce a version of the image with lat-long coordinates defined. This can be done by stretching, rotating, or even warping the image (like it was on a rubber sheet) to a new image that is a lat-long grid.

There can be various complications to this depending on how accurate to the ground truth the image is, what sort of map projection it was created with and so on. But look into "GeoReferencing".

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!